Correlated groups: mixed effects as a factor model
This has already been posted in quant exchange, but there's been no interest, so I thought I might repost it here.
I am trying to build a fundamental factor model in the style of Fama-French. I have the FF factors as well as the industries in which my assets belong. For those unfamiliar with FF, you can view this as some fundamental factor (same as inflation, or GDP, let's say)
The model is specified as:
$$
\mathbf{Y} = \mathbf{X}\beta + \mathbf{Z}\gamma + \epsilon 
$$
where, $\mathbf{Y}$ is a cross-sectional time-series matrix of $N$ assets and $T$ weekly returns; $\mathbf{X}$ are the Fama-French factors (weekly returns of the HML, SMB, WML and Market-RF portfolios); $\mathbf{Z}$ is a matrix of random effects. I have a simple case whereby there are only random intercepts and no random slopes, i.e., $\mathbf{Z}$ is a matrix of 1s and 0s indicating the industry in which the asset belongs. $\epsilon$ are the residuals which are distributed $N(0,1)$, $\gamma$ are the random intercepts $N(0,\mathbf{G})$ and $\beta$ are the usual, fixed slopes (and one fixed intercept) in this case.
We can fit this model using statsmodels' mixed linear model.
The dataframe looks like this:

We fit the model by simply:
md = smf.mixedlm("y ~ MktRF + SMB + HML + WML", X,  groups=X["sector"])
res = md.fit()

The summary is shown below. The results are horrible, however. There is almost a perfect linear relationship between the residuals and the fitted values.


My suspicion is that something is off with the covariance matrix, $\mathbf{G}$ since this is close to singular. One of the common approaches I read about regarding this issue is that the random effects might be overparametrized and that multicollinearity might be present there. Hence, I computed (with some padding out of neccessity) the correlations between the industries - our random intercepts.

Well, yes, the groups are correlated with one another (especially some groups).
Questions:

What can we do about this? I could regroup some of the industries that are correlated, but this doesn't seem to be a great idea. For example, 'Financials' and 'Industrials' are quite correlated, but these are quite different groups and might have different correlations with other groups.

Is the covariance really an issue? Could be something else as well? I have read this post that talks about how having a zero variance doesn't neccessarily mean that something is wrong with the model, i.e., it could be that there is no group-variation and that all the variation is captured by the residual variation - but this still does not explain the linear relationship between the data and the residuals.



The covariance $\mathbf{G}$ is not what causes this issue. The issue persists even in a simple OLS specification, as well as in a fixed-effects specification.
Since both $\mathbf{X}$ and $\mathbf{Y}$ are returns, there is an omitted variable bias. $\mathbf{X}$ are weekly returns of assets in SP500, while $\mathbf{Y}$ are weekly returns of certain portfolios (based on FF formulae and quantile segmentations), again, of assets in the US market (or developed) markets. Hence, if there are most likely some unobserved factors that influence that influece both $\mathbf{X}$ and $\mathbf{Y}$.
This could be formally shown as follows. Suppose the true model is given by:
$$
\mathbf{Y} = \mathbf{X}\beta + \mathbf{U}\phi + \mathbf{Z}\gamma + \epsilon
$$
Suppose we omit $\mathbf{U}$ and the relationship between $\mathbf{U}$ and $\mathbf{X}$
$$
\mathbf{U} = \mathbf{X}\alpha + u
$$
What we will essentially estimate is actually:
$$
\mathbf{Y} = \mathbf{X}\beta + (\mathbf{X}\alpha + u)\phi + \mathbf{Z}\gamma + \epsilon \\
\mathbf{Y} = \mathbf{X}(\beta + \alpha\phi) + \mathbf{Z}\gamma + (u\phi+\epsilon)
$$
Hence, if $\phi$ (slope) is non-zero, there is a linear relationship between the residuals and the dependent variable.
